# Pebble JS SDK: how to catch & react on an external app notification

Tags: javascript, android, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, pebble-js

I have a weather app which sends a notification about an upcoming rain. 
This is a standalone app, runs on Android/iOS.

Is there a way to catch a notification from the app and show some info on the watch screen with Pebble JS SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Android's `NotificationListenerService`. There is more information on how to use this in it's documentation, found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html).